# Getting Error message in dashboard

Tags: reporting, dashboard

In one of our dashboards we are getting the below error message for a particular report. Other reports are displaying in dashboard as expected.
**Error Message:**
`Error: Warning: The results below may be incomplete because the underlying report produced too many summary rows, and the sort order of the component is different from the sort order in the underlying report. Try adding filters to the report to reduce the number of rows returned.`

Could anyone please let me know what we supposed to do in order to make it visible in dashboard.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like that the report from which this dashboard is created has :-

- a good number of groupings over large data set.
- few grouping but resulting into two many grouped results. For example "group by date type field" for a data collected in a year.

Try to reduce grouping field from report or use a grouping field which created less number of grouped rows in report.